# Tem como fazer uma MAPA DE CALOR em uma imagem?

Tags: javascript, css

Eu estou utilizando a planta de uma casa, dentro das peças da casa, possuem sensores. Eu quero fazer um mapa de calor, mapeando os locais onde mais se disparam os sensores, mas não sei por onde começar. Eu estou tentando fazer umas gambiarras com CSS, mas pelo que pesquisei, se usa JavaScript, só que ainda to perdido nisso

Comment: Refaça sua pergunta sendo mais objetivo, não sabemos se você quer construir uma aplicação que gere um mapa de calor para qualquer imagem inserida ou simplesmente editar apenas uma imagem.

Comment: O que acha de fazer um contator de cada sensor na casa, ai vai ter a quantidade, pode usar essa quantidade para escurecer a cor, pode fazer isso via javascript, pesquise sobre.
Agora voce vai ter um sensor em cada ponto da sua planta definida no seu css por id, via javascript voce pode manipular isso.

Answer (score 1):

Existem várias maneiras de implementar um *heatmap*. Caso você queira utilizar algo já pronto, [Heatmap.js](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/) é uma biblioteca javascript que faz exatamente isso. De acordo com sua documentação, a biblioteca suporta até 40.000 pontos por mapa.

[Este é um exemplo que pode lhe ser útil](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/example-click-heatmap.html).